# How can we create event class using php artisan in laravel 4.1?

Tags: laravel-4

I want to create event class in Laravel 4.1 using "PHP artisan" command. I have found for 5.1 version but unable to dump for 4.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4 doesn't have this feature but it has generators package to extend some artisan commands:

```
generate:model
generate:view
generate:controller
generate:seed
generate:migration
generate:pivot
generate:resource
generate:scaffold
```

You can find it in:
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators